# iOS in app purchase App Store Server Notifications delay in sandbox

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have integrated App Store Server Notifications to listen iOS in app purchase subscriptions. I have set 5 minutes interval for my sandbox account. Some time notifications coming on time, but some time it is delayed. Will this be happen in production also? Any proper way to test this?